# CountDown Timer with a progressbar?

Tags: android, progress-bar, countdowntimer

I have created CountDown Timer with a progressbar that should show progress how much time has passed, for example, 10 to 0 (seconds) (when it reaches 2.5-sec progress bar should complete 25%, 5-sec progress bar should complete 50%, it should update every second) but Progressbar is not working properly

**activity_timer.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TimerActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/TimerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"


            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TimerTV"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/_00_00"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="70sp"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/circular_progress_bar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/TimerTV"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:indeterminate="false"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular"
                android:visibility="visible" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="30dp"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="348dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/StartPauseButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
                android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:text="@string/start"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,NotSibling" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ResetButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="56dp"
                android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:text="@string/reset"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
                tools:visibility="invisible" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**circular.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:useLevel="true"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="3.8sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />

</shape>
```

**TimerActivity.java**

```
    package killer.timer;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.CountDownTimer;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.Locale;

    public class TimerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private static final long START_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 20000; //20sec

    //    TODO Accept Input from user & store it in  START_TIME_IN_MILLIS
        int progress;

        private TextView CountDown_Tv;
        private Button StartPauseButton;
        private Button ResetButton;

        private CountDownTimer MyCountDownTimer;
        private boolean TimerRunning;

    //        Initially TimeLeftInMillis will be same as START_TIME_IN_MILLIS
        private long TimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;

        ProgressBar MyProgressBar;
        private int  ProgressBarStatus;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);

            CountDown_Tv = findViewById(R.id.TimerTV);

            StartPauseButton = findViewById(R.id.StartPauseButton);
            ResetButton = findViewById(R.id.ResetButton);
            MyProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.circular_progress_bar);

            StartPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (TimerRunning) {
                        pauseTimer();
                    } else {
                        startTimer();
                    }
                }
            });

            ResetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    resetTimer();
                }
            });

            updateCountDownText();

            MyProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            MyProgressBar.setProgress(0);
            MyProgressBar.setMax(100);


        }

        private void startTimer() {
            MyCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(START_TIME_IN_MILLIS, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    TimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                    updateCountDownText(); //  Updating CountDown_Tv


/*for incrementing progressbar every second calculating progress for every second*/
                    progress = (int) (START_TIME_IN_MILLIS / (1 * 100));
                    //incrementing progress on every tick                   
                    ProgressBarStatus +=progress; 
                    MyProgressBar.setProgress(ProgressBarStatus); 

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    TimerRunning = false;
                    CountDown_Tv.setText("00:00");
                    MyProgressBar.setProgress(100);
                    StartPauseButton.setText("Start");
                    StartPauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    ResetButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }.start();

            TimerRunning = true;
            StartPauseButton.setText("Pause");
            ResetButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        }

        private void pauseTimer() {
            MyCountDownTimer.cancel();
            TimerRunning = false;
            StartPauseButton.setText("Resume");
            ResetButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            MyProgressBar.clearAnimation();
        }

        private void resetTimer() {
            TimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
            updateCountDownText();
            ResetButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            StartPauseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

      MyProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        StartPauseButton.setText("Start");
    }

    private void updateCountDownText() {
        int minutes = (int) (TimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
        int seconds = (int) (TimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;


            String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);

    //        String newtime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

            CountDown_Tv.setText(timeLeftFormatted);

        }

  }
```

Comment: Not working properly how? What is it doing compared to what you expect it to do?

Comment: you are using a 20000 for START_TIME_IN_MILLIS; isn't it 10000 for 10 sec?

Comment: Progressbar is not increasing gradually as expected. It should update every second as time decreases.

Comment: @M.Zain it was just an example, I want to take input from user (later) which will be stored in  START_TIME_IN_MILLIS

Comment: Is there some problem with my calculations                                            progress = (int) (START_TIME_IN_MILLIS / (1 * 100));

Comment: What is the point of 1*100?

Comment: @codeMagic was trying to calculate the percentage factor based on the total number of seconds like Krishna Sharma did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate the percentage factor based on total number of seconds to be countdown. For example in your case `100/START_TIME_IN_MILLIS/1000 = 5`; 
after all need to multiply this for each tick count.

[image]

Here is the modified code.

```
int numberOfSeconds = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS/1000; // Ex : 20000/1000 = 20
int factor = 100/numberOfSeconds; // 100/20 = 5, for each second multiply this, for sec 1 progressPercentage = 1x5 =5, for sec 5 progressPercentage = 5x5 = 25, for sec 20 progressPercentage = 20x5 =100
@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    TimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
    updateCountDownText(); //  Updating CountDown_Tv
    int secondsRemaining = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    int progressPercentage = (numberOfSeconds-secondsRemaining) * factor ;
    MyProgressBar.setProgress(progressPercentage);
}
```

Comment: A good answer typically provides some description as to why your code should work and what it changes instead of just a code dump

Comment: @KrishnaSharma Thanks, It worked!! But on the last tick, it stops for a while (not as smooth as the beginning) and then onFinish() is fired can you help?

Comment: @Keval Glad to know it worked. It should had to work fine for the last tick count as well as you are calling **MyProgressBar.setProgress(100);** in onFinish.

Answer (score -1):

Your calculation should be like this i guess:

```
progress = (int) (((startTime - remainingTime)/startTime) * 100);
MyProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
```

Comment: A good answer typically describes what the problem is and why your change fixes it so the OP can understand better what was wrong to try and prevent it in the future